# Senior Citizen pyjamas trouble

Tags: clothing

Am a senior citizen with no muscle mass, and I'm fat.  My pyjamas keep slipping despite knotting hard. Can't wear elastic due to abdominal discomfort. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 4):

You have a variety of different casual/lounge wear to substitute for pyjama pants from… 
a Mediterranean kaftan: [image: kaftan] to 
a bathrobe: [image: bathrobe] to 
a sleep robe: [image: sleep robe] to

 … nothing at all (wear a smile).

Good Luck.

Comment: Up until recent modern times, the first image was in fact what people wore to bed. Ever watch ***A Christmas Carol***. Ebenezer Scrooge wore something ever similar. I have also seen historical forms in image 3, though a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

**Pyjama Party Lifehack**:

The easiest solution to pyjama pants dropsy is a pair of suspenders so that your waistband can be loose but stay put for your lounge wear.

They can be as simple as you wish. You can buy a pair with clips so that you don't need much preparation. I made a pair out of three large safety pins and a length of some nice bulky soft yarn.

Here's how:

- Use one pin for the centre of the back of the pyjama bottoms.
- Use one pin for each side of the front.
- Pass one end of the yarn to through the loop of the rear pin. Knot it so that it stays in the middle.
- Pass each end through the loops of each of the front pins and tie. The yarn will now have the shape of a 'Y' with pins at each end and the middle.
- Let the yarn hang over each shoulder to support the pyjama pants comfortably. Adjust the length to 'suit' yourself. (That was intended as a bad pun.)

[image: DIY pyjama pants suspenders]

Good luck.

Comment: Might be uncomfortable during sleeping, during the accommodation phase, but doable. Funny out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

By replacing with a pyjama **onesie suit**

[image]

<sup>*Image from [Alibaba.com](https://www.alibaba.com/)*</sup>

Comment: And the next question will be: "How to I open the onesie quickly at the bathroom, if my hands are slow?" The idea is funny, I admit it, but it might be impractical in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Look for a pair of pajamas that have a soft tie—just enough to hold them up but not so tight that they're uncomfortable. Amazon has some great options.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Maybe you can add some detail, what do you consider a soft tie? And why your "soft tie" is not someone else's "hard tie"? And a picture might help too.